# Rigify not working at all

Tags: rigify

Blender ver 4.76.
Rigify is enabled. Does python scripting auto have to be on?
Imported a model but When selecting Armature, Human Meta Rig, no rig shows up. Nothing appears.

Comment: Did you activate the addon in the user preferences?

Comment: yes for rigify you need to either have auto-python script, or you might need to "reload trusted" it per .blend file when you open it. see http://www.pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=99752